Connecting a Fourier Transform series expansion to the Dirichlet Distribution and Dirichlet Process
I have derived an expression for the Fourier transform of the position distribution of a certain one-dimensional stochastic process, and I suspect it is related to the Dirichlet process or Dirichlet distribution. However, I am not very familiar with these concepts and need help making the connection. The expression I have is:
\begin{equation}
\hat{p}(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(ik)^{2n}}{(2\mu)^n\, (\frac{\beta}{2})^{(n)}}\, Z_n\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\langle D\rangle,\ldots, \frac{\beta}{2}\langle D^n \rangle\right)\, .
\end{equation}
where $(\frac{\beta}{2})^{(n)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\beta}{2}+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}$ is the Pochhammer symbol, $Z_n$ is the cycle index of the symmetric group. And $\langle D^n \rangle$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ moment of a distribution that I call $w(D)$.
In the paper "Characteristic Functionals of Dirichlet Measures" by Lorenzo Dello Schiavo, I noticed that the coefficients in my series expansion are almost identical to those of a Dirichlet distribution. However, I am struggling to make a precise connection between the parameters. Additionally, my summation is over $(ik)^{2n}$, whereas their summation is over $(it)^n$.
Here are the relevant excerpts from the paper:


Could someone help me understand the connection between my result and the Dirichlet distribution? How can I align the parameters and terms to see the relationship more clearly?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
